# Displaying timeago in laravel in the view

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am using `laravel` and I have a foreach loop in my blade view where I display all the players from the database. I am saving their property birthday as a string in this kind of format `30/11/1994`. Instead of showing their birthday in that kind of format, what is the easiest way of displaying the date and timeago of each the player in the view in the format like this:

```
born Nov 30, 1994, 22 years old
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Laravel Carbon

```
$birthday = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $birthday);

//in blade
Born on {{ $birthday->toFormattedDateString() }}, {{ $birthday->age }} years old

//will display 'Born on Nov 30, 1994, 22 Years old
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating a custom helper function and utilizing [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) like so:

```
function getBirthdateAndAgeString($date_str) {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_str);
    $age = $now->year - $date->year;

    return 'born ' . $date->format('M d, Y') . ', ' . $age . ' years old';
}
```